# Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'linear' of undefined

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to get load data from `iris.CSV` and plot it in the web page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>D3 Example</title>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", 250)
            .attr("height", 250);

        var xScale = d3.scale.linear().range([0, 250]);
        var yScale = d3.scale.linear().range([0, 250]);

        function render(data) {

            xScale.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
                return d.sepal_length;
            }));
            yScale.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
                return d.petal_length;
            }));

            var circles = svg.selectAll("circle").data(data);
            circles.enter().append("circle").attr("r", 10);
            circles
                .attr("cx", function(d) {
                    return xScale(d.sepal_length);
                })
                .attr("cy", function(d) {
                    return yScale(d.petal_length);
                });

            circles.exit().remove();
        }

        function type(d) {
            d.sepal_length = +d.sepal_length;
            d.sepal_width = +d.sepal_width;
            d.petal_length = +d.petal_length;
            d.petal_width = +d.petal_width;
            return d;
        }

        d3.csv("iris.csv", type, render);
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

But I am getting an error in it.

> Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'linear' of undefined

I even changed `linear` for `scaleLinear` for d3.v4., which is also showing the error.

Comment: Apart from the single `</script>` tag in the `<head>` the code looks ok. Since the `d3.select()` prior to the scale's declaration seems to work, this should not be the cause of your problem, though. Please set-up a [mcve] demonstrating the effect. When doing so, please reduce and clean up the code as much as possible

Comment: Even I'm getting "Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: HTTP, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https" error.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work for me (I didn't have the CSV file so I just used some fake data):

```js
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", 250)
  .attr("height", 250);

var xScale = d3.scale.linear().range([10, 240]);
var yScale = d3.scale.linear().range([10, 240]);

function render(data) {

  xScale.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
    return d.sepal_length;
  }));
  yScale.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
    return d.petal_length;
  }));

  var circles = svg.selectAll("circle").data(data);
  circles.enter().append("circle").attr("r", 10);
  circles
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
      return xScale(d.sepal_length);
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
      return yScale(d.petal_length);
    });

  circles.exit().remove();
}

function type(d) {
  d.sepal_length = +d.sepal_length;
  d.sepal_width = +d.sepal_width;
  d.petal_length = +d.petal_length;
  d.petal_width = +d.petal_width;
  return d;
}

render([{
    sepal_length: 10,
    petal_length: 20,
  },
  {
    sepal_length: 15,
    petal_length: 18,
  }
])
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I used <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script> and i'm getting this error: XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///D:/Zjtryiris.csv. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Comment: The problem is this code is not working in Google chrome. But working in Mozilla firefox. Why is it so?

Comment: The file needs to be served by a webserver. Try running a local webserver, if you have python you can run `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` and then point your browser to `http://localhost:8000`